# Page headers in uppercase (amsbook+chapterbib+natbib)

Tags: header-footer, capitalization, amsbook

I have the following problem which has been driving me crazy for quite some time now. Using the [`amsbook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsbook) class for whatever you are intending to use it for, in the end you will end up having your page headers in uppercase, e.g., PREFACE, ..., BIBLIOGRAPHY, ... Needless to say that the contents list simply plots Preface, ..., Bibliography; so far so good. Now, say we are to use [`chapterbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib), in combination with its option `sectionbib`, to include bibliography sections in each of our chapters. Then, again, these will be printed in our contents list as Bibliography - not necessarily numbered, which is fair enough - belonging to our chapters. However, for some strange reason, the page headers belonging to the bibliography sections now show Bibliography rather than the uppercase BIBLIOGRAPHY which one might have expected. My question is: how do we get these in uppercase? Please note that this problem should be treated in the context of using `amsbook` class only.

Further, simply putting `\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}` in each chapter file to be included (following `\bibliography`) does not help really - it changes the page header only for the last page of the bibliography section.

For example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{amsbook}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{An Example}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{preface}

\end{document}
```

where

```
% This is preface.tex
\chapter*{Preface}

\markboth{PREFACE}{PREFACE}

Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.
Test \cite{Kalman1960}. Test \cite{KalmanBucy1961}. Test \cite{LukesRussell1969}.
Test \cite{Komornik1994}. Test \cite{Lions1988a}. Test \cite{Gearhart1978}.
Test \cite{Huang1985}. Test \cite{Pruss1984}. Test \cite{HutsonPym1980}.
Test \cite{Kreyszig1978}. Test \cite{ReedSimon1972}. Test \cite{TaylorLay1980}.
Test \cite{Evans1998}. Test \cite{Gustafson1980}. Test \cite{RenardyRogers2004}.
Test \cite{Balakrishnan1974}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{D:/BibLioTest}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}
```

and

```
% This is BibLioTest.bib
@article {Kalman1960,
    AUTHOR = {Kalman, R. E.},
     TITLE = {Contributions to the theory of optimal control},
   JOURNAL = {Bolet{\'i}n de la Sociedad Matem{\'a}tica Mexicana},
    VOLUME = {5},
      YEAR = {1960},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {102--119},
}

@article {KalmanBucy1961,
    AUTHOR = {Kalman, R. E. and Bucy, R. S.},
     TITLE = {New results in linear filtering and prediction theory},
   JOURNAL = {Transactions of the ASME. Series D: Journal of Basic Engineering},
    VOLUME = {83},
      YEAR = {1961},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {95--108},
}

@article {LukesRussell1969,
    AUTHOR = {Lukes, D. L. and Russell, D. L.},
     TITLE = {The quadratic criterion for distributed systems},
   JOURNAL = {SIAM Journal on Control},
    VOLUME = {7},
      YEAR = {1969},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {101--121},
}

@book {Komornik1994,
    AUTHOR = {Komornik, V.},
     TITLE = {Exact {C}ontrollability and {S}tabilization: The {M}ultiplier {M}ethod},
    SERIES = {Research in Applied Mathematics (RAM)},
 PUBLISHER = {John Wiley \& Sons},
   ADDRESS = {Chichester, West Sussex, UK},
      YEAR = {1994},
}

@book {Lions1988a,
    AUTHOR = {Lions, J.-L.},
     TITLE = {Contr\^olabilit\'e Exacte, Perturbations et Stabilisation de Syst\`emes Distribu\'es. {T}ome 1: Contr\^olabilit\'e Exacte},
      NOTE = {(In French)},
    SERIES = {Recherches en Math\'ematiques Appliqu\'ees (RMA)},
    VOLUME = {8},
 PUBLISHER = {Masson},
   ADDRESS = {Paris, France},
      YEAR = {1988},
}

@article {Gearhart1978,
    AUTHOR = {Gearhart, L.},
     TITLE = {Spectral theory for contraction semigroups on {H}ilbert space},
   JOURNAL = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
    VOLUME = {236},
      YEAR = {1978},
     PAGES = {385--394},
}

@article {Huang1985,
    AUTHOR = {Huang, F. L.},
     TITLE = {Characteristic conditions for exponential stability of linear dynamical systems in {H}ilbert spaces},
   JOURNAL = {Annals of Differential Equations},
    VOLUME = {1},
      YEAR = {1985},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {43--56},
}

@article {Pruss1984,
    AUTHOR = {Pr{\"u}ss, J.},
     TITLE = {On the spectrum of {$C_0$}-semigroups},
   JOURNAL = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
    VOLUME = {284},
      YEAR = {1984},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {847--857},
}

@book {HutsonPym1980,
    AUTHOR = {Hutson, V. and Pym, J. S.},
     TITLE = {Applications of {F}unctional {A}nalysis and {O}perator {T}heory},
    SERIES = {Mathematics in Science and Engineering},
    VOLUME = {146},
 PUBLISHER = {Academic Press},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {1980},
}

@book {Kreyszig1978,
    AUTHOR = {Kreyszig, E.},
     TITLE = {Introductory {F}unctional {A}nalysis with {A}pplications},
 PUBLISHER = {John Wiley \& Sons},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {1978},
}

@book {ReedSimon1972,
    AUTHOR = {Reed, M. and Simon, B.},
     TITLE = {Methods of {M}odern {M}athematical {P}hysics.\ {I}: {F}unctional {A}nalysis},
 PUBLISHER = {Academic Press},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {1972},
}

@book {TaylorLay1980,
    AUTHOR = {Taylor, A. E. and Lay, D. C.},
     TITLE = {Introduction to {F}unctional {A}nalysis},
 PUBLISHER = {John Wiley \& Sons},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {1980},
}

@book {Evans1998,
    AUTHOR = {Evans, L. C.},
     TITLE = {Partial {D}ifferential {E}quations},
    SERIES = {Graduate Studies in Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {19},
 PUBLISHER = {American Mathematical Society (AMS)},
   ADDRESS = {Providence, RI, USA},
      YEAR = {1998},
}

@book {Gustafson1980,
    AUTHOR = {Gustafson, K. E.},
     TITLE = {Introduction to {P}artial {D}ifferential {E}quations and {H}ilbert {S}pace {M}ethods},
 PUBLISHER = {John Wiley \& Sons},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {1980},
}

@book {RenardyRogers2004,
    AUTHOR = {Renardy, M. and Rogers, R. C.},
     TITLE = {An {I}ntroduction to {P}artial {D}ifferential {E}quations},
    SERIES = {Texts in Applied Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {13},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York, NY, USA},
      YEAR = {2004},
}

@article {Balakrishnan1974,
    AUTHOR = {Balakrishnan, A. V.},
     TITLE = {Stochastic optimization theory in {H}ilbert spaces -- I},
   JOURNAL = {Applied Mathematics \& Optimization},
    VOLUME = {1},
      YEAR = {1974},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {97--120},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you if you don't show a minimal example of your input.

Comment: I guess you're right; I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

well, i've figured out why `chapterbib` causes the running heads to be uncapitalized.

`amsbook` depends on these definition for all running heads:

```
\def\partrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}{\uppercase{\ignorespaces#1 #2\unskip}\@ifnotempty{#3}{. }}%
  \def\@tempa{#3}%
  \ifx\@empty\@tempa\else
    \begingroup \def\\{ \ignorespaces}% defend against questionable usage
    \uppercasenonmath\@tempa\@tempa
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\let\chapterrunhead\partrunhead
\let\sectionrunhead\partrunhead
```

notice where the `\uppercasenonmath` is applied.  the relevant marks are produced from `#3` in this process.

`chapterbib` redefines the way these marks are set, as

```
 \csname#2mark\endcsname{\bibname}
```

buried deep within the definition of `\sectionbib` (which defines the behavior for a chapter as well as for a section) so in effect the `amsbook` definition isn't applied at all (for the bibliography) when `chapterbib` is used.

it looks like the most expedient way to get uppercased running heads for the references is to intervene *after* `\begin{thebibliography}` (in the `.bbl` file).  your code

```
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}
```

will work as intended there.

an alternative approach would be to get rid of uppercasing entirely, by redefining `\partrunhead` to omit `\uppercasenonmath` and then reiterating the two `\let` statements.

i haven't investigated whether `natbib.sty` redefines how the running heads are set, but it probably does.

Answer (score 1):

Use this trick:

```
\renewcommand\bibsection{\section*{\bibname}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}
```

The fact is that `natbib` takes over `chapterbib` and it has

```
\@ifclassloaded{amsbook}{\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}}}{}
```

In this case `chapterbib` just changes `\chapter` to `\section`, but adding the `\markboth` command does what you want.

<sub>Note: personally I dislike uppercased headers. :)</sub>

Comment: i dislike uppercased headers too, but other folks define the specs.